# Is there any terraform resource (or CLI commands) for oauth config in GCP, also to add Authorized domains in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, terraform, google-cloud-dns

[image]
[image]
I would like to know if is there any terraform resource (or command line) to do the following tasks in Google Cloud Platform (GCP):

1. Add an authorized DNS domain in API & Services --> Oauth consent screen (please see the attached image/screenshot above).
2. Add authorized redirect URIs in Client ID for web application (please see another attached image/screenshot above).

The question is due to I need to automate those tasks for a production deployment, but I have not found a way to automate it (preferably using terraforming code, through native resources or null resources), or in any other way.

thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Platform API to configure OAuth2 consent and credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584516/google-cloud-platform-api-to-configure-oauth2-consent-and-credentials)

Answer (score 3):

This must be completed in the Google Cloud Console. There are no public APIs nor CLI commands that provide these features.

Comment: Thanks John. I will work on a workaround (surely through the Google Console) to address it.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question a few years ago. I wonder if at this time there are any terraform (or command line) resources to do what I described in the original question.

Thanks,